# Can Server Essentials be used with file replication service with server standard as the domain controller?

Tags: windows-server-2019

We are planning on implementing a windows server 2019 standard with File replication to other remote servers.  Was hoping to run these as Windows server essentials as they won't be domain controllers (leaving that for the Windows Server 2019 standard).  Essentially we are looking at a way of saving costs, rather than having a number of full servers.

Is this possible, or does the Essentials server have an issue sitting on the same domain (although it is not a domain controller) as another server that is the domain controller?

Is there another option that is better?

Answer (score 0):

After some research it is apparent that a Server essentials can only have one instance on the domain and secondary servers must be Server standard. Server essentials must hold the FSMO and domain controller roles, and doesn't allow for a secondary domain controller.